# Minor ticks like a ruler on a dynamic axis with D3

Tags: d3.js

To make things look a little nicer, I've been trying to make use of a variation on [the tickSubDivide workaround](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349486).  I got [the result I wanted here](http://jsbin.com/UhaxawU/4), but my implementation was extremely limited (change the slider and things don't look so pretty anymore).

I changed my tack and tried to calculate the "fake" axis based on the tick count from the "real" axis, but I ran into more problems when I realized that it wasn't just the tick count changing, but the values that each tick represents.

My next step is is to iterate through each `.tick` and generate new `line` elements in between the tick I'm on and the next tick, and then go back and fill in the ticks at the beginning... this seems like it'll become a bear.

I'm wondering if it wouldn't be worth not using `axis` to do this... perhaps creating the ticks myself might be more efficient in the long run?

I figured I'd ask the experts **if there is a better way to pull this off**, before I end up doing something silly.

In case it wasn't apparent, the effect I'm going for is this:

```
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  1  |  |  |  2  |  |  |  3  |  |
|           |           |           |
```

but will probably end up settling for this:

```
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
|     1     |     2     |     3     |
|           |           |           |
```

The scale's range/domain needs to be entirely dynamic.

**Edit**: Did I mention I wanted to use `d3.time.scale`?  My first sweep produces some weird results... see the difference between 202 and 203 on the slider (use the keyboard to get accuracy):

http://jsbin.com/InEFISa/4/edit

**Edit II**: Made another attempt that involved filling in existing ticks..

http://jsbin.com/AmIFAci/1/edit

I imagine what I'm doing is costly, but I've not measured performance.  It's also somewhat sloppy... I'm calling `minorAxisGroup.selectAll('g').remove()` instead of binding my newly constructed `points` array with `.data()`, which isn't in the spirit of D3.  I'll probably adjust that.

I'll try extending `.axis()` another time.  I'm not entirely sure how to go about rendering twice as many ticks as possible... I have a few ideas but also some concerns.

Comment: It does sound like you would want to have your own axis implementation, certainly if you want to reuse it. The current implementation would be a good place to start and it shouldn't be too much work. Trying to tack this onto the existing implementation will be quite messy I think.